# Windows phone 8 Button style is transparent

Tags: xaml, button, text, windows-phone-8, styles

My button looks like a text field instead of a button. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<Button FontWeight="Bold" Click="setWallpaper" Foreground="black"  FontSize="35" 
    Margin="62,560,127,48" >Set Lockscreen</Button>
```

How do I fix it and make it look like a good old button?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is that you have an image as your background and the button is transparent so it is showing the image.  Just change your button background to White and it should fix it

```
<Button FontWeight="Bold" Click="setWallpaper" Foreground="Black"  FontSize="35" Background="White" Margin="62,560,127,48" >Set Lockscreen</Button>
```